# Emulator - how to add web browser and Samsung Apps?

Tags: bada

I have just installed Bada emulator and it has only settings. Is there any how how to add there web browser and Samsung Apps icon portal. I would like to test some current apps on this emulator.

Thanks for reply

Hmyzak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the web browser, there's a trick you can do:
Write an app which starts it. The code basically would be

```
ArrayList* pDataList = null;
pDataList = new ArrayList();
pDataList->Construct();

String* pData = null;
pData = new String(L"http://www.someurl.com");
pDataList->Add(*pData);
AppControl* pAc = AppManager::FindAppControlN(APPCONTROL_BROWSER, "");
pAc->Start(pDataList, null);
```

That starts a browser in Emulator. I don't think that's possible for the AppStore.

Comment: What libraries do I have to include? Added this exact code to a button and got the following errors.

'APPCONTROL_BROWSER' was not declared in this scope
'AppControl' was not declared in this scope
'AppManager' has not been declared
'ArrayList' was not declared in this scope
'pAc' was not declared in this scope
'pDataList' was not declared in this scope
expected ';' before 'ArrayList'
expected type-specifier before 'ArrayList'